# Is my ColdFusion server startup time slowed by too many datasources?

Tags: coldfusion

My ColdFusion services are taking many minutes to start, I suspect that the number of datasources may play a part, it seems that ColdFusion attempts to establish a connection with each datasource on start, is this true, could it be the source of y slow startup times?

Comment: Addditional jar files in your class path increase startup time. Datasources are not verified on server startup afaik.

Comment: Even if it were true, if you needed all the datasources you would simply have to accept it.

Comment: Check this article by Charlie Arehart - [Solving slow CF startup: my elaborating on an Adobe blog entry on a possible solution](http://www.carehart.org/blog/client/index.cfm/2015/1/30/elaborating_on_an_Adobe_blog_entry_today_re_cfclasses)

Comment: It looks like my logs have "A non-SQL error occurred while requesting a connection from [DSNNAME]. Timed out trying to establish connection" during an unsuccessful startup attempt.

Comment: Is that when the application server starts or when a particular application starts?

Comment: When the application server starts, before any requests have been attempted, before the service says it is Running